# Jenkins pipeline conditional stage using "When" for choice parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a jenkins pipeline where I have a choice parameter with n choices and want to create a `stage` which does something when some values from the choice parameter are selected
I have something like below but doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

agent any

    parameters {

        choice(
                choices: 'a\nb\n\c\n\d\ne\nf',
                description: 'name of the student',
                name: 'name'
        )
    }
 stages {
       stage ('callNames') {

        when {
             expression { params.name == 'a|d|f' }
        }
        steps{
        echo "selected name is: ${name}"
        //do something

            }
        }        
    }
}
```

So, I want to `do something` when the selected values for the parameter `name` are either `a` or `d` of `f`
For the above, I get no errors but I am seeing this in the console output

`Stage 'callNames' skipped due to when conditional` when I select the value `a/d/f` during the build

Please let me know what's missing here
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `when` expression has an error. If your parameter's `name` value is `'a'`, you are comparing strings `'a' == 'a|d|f'` in your code, which is `false`.

You probably want to do

```
when {
    expression { 
        params.name == 'a' ||
        params.name == 'd' ||
        params.name == 'f' 
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer oneliner, you can use regular expression

```
when {
    expression { 
        params.name ==~ /a|d|f/
    }
}
```