# Jenkins Pipeline with conditional "When" expression of choice parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to Groovy. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong here.

Depends on the choice of input, I expect the script to execute either Step 'Hello' or 'Bye' but it skips both. I mostly orientated to this [Jenkins pipeline conditional stage using "When" for choice parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381586/jenkins-pipeline-conditional-stage-using-when-for-choice-parameters), but still can't figure it out.

How can I use those choice parameters correctly?

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Init') {
          steps('Log-in'){
            echo 'Log-in'
            }
        }
      stage('Manual Step') {
            input {
              message "Hello or Goodbye?"
              ok "Say!"
              parameters{choice(choices:['Hello','Bye'], description: 'Users Choice', name: 'CHOICE')}
            }
            steps('Input'){
                echo "choice: ${CHOICE}"
                echo "choice params.: " + params.CHOICE     //null          
                echo "choice env: " + env.CHOICE            //Hello 
            }
        }
      stage('Hello') {
        when{ expression {env.CHOICE == 'Hello'}}       
          steps('Execute'){
            echo 'Say Hello'
            } 
        }       
      stage('Bye') {
        when{ expression {env.CHOICE == 'Bye'}}
          steps('Execute'){
            echo 'Say Bye'    
              }
        }
      
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Init)
[Pipeline] echo
Log-in
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Manual Step)
[Pipeline] input
Input requested
Approved by Admin
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
choice: Hello
[Pipeline] echo
choice params.: null
[Pipeline] echo
choice env: Hello
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
Stage "Hello" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Bye)
Stage "Bye" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input):

> Any parameters provided as part of the input submission will be available in the environment for the rest of the stage.

This means that your parameter `CHOICE` does not exist in the other stages. If you want to have a parameter that's available on all the stages, you can define a parameter outside of the stage, i.e.:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
   
    parameters {
        choice(choices:['Hello','Bye'], description: 'Users Choice', name: 'CHOICE')
    }
   
   stages {
        stage('Init') {
            steps('Log-in') {
                echo 'Log-in'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Manual Step') {
            steps('Input') {
                echo "choice: ${CHOICE}"
                echo "choice params.: " + params.CHOICE
                echo "choice env: " + env.CHOICE
            }
        }
        
        stage('Hello') {
            when { 
                expression { env.CHOICE == 'Hello' }
            }   
            
            steps('Execute')    {
                echo 'Say Hello'
            } 
        }       
        
        stage('Bye') {
            when {
                expression {env.CHOICE == 'Bye'}
            }
            
            steps('Execute'){
                echo 'Say Bye'    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will behave as expected. The difference is that the job won't ask you for input, instead, you will provide the wanted parameters before pressing build.

Comment: Thank you Vivere, just out of curiousity, is it possible to assign an input value to global variables aswell?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's kinda anti-pattern. In your example, in the stage `Manual Step` you could open a `script block` and write something like: `env.MyChoice = CHOICE`, then `MyChoice` will be available afterwards.